# Thrones at the end of days

Tags: revelation

In a recent television preaching program I heard the teacher say that there are three thrones: one for the God, one for the Jesus, and one for the Holy Spirit.

He also said that he could find this only in a very old version of Bible.

In Revelation 20:11 it is said that :

> Then I saw a great white throne and him who was seated on it. The earth and the heavens fled from his presence, and there was no place for them.

Is the grammatical antecedent of "them" (last word in this verse) in reference to the throne and those seated?

In other words, does the grammatical structure of this verse indicate "one in three," and therefore "three in one"?

Answer (score 6):

Here's the Greek text of [Rev. 20:11](http://www.blueletterbible.org/Bible.cfm?b=Rev&c=20&t=KJV#s=t_conc_1187011) according to the Textus Receptus (the NA28 varies slightly in word order, but it does not change the meaning of the text):

> Καὶ εἶδον θρόνον λευκὸν μέγαν καὶ τὸν καθήμενον ἐπ᾽ αὐτοῦ, οὗ ἀπὸ προσώπου ἔφυγεν ἡ γῆ καὶ ὁ οὐρανός καὶ τόπος οὐχ εὑρέθη αὐτοῖς

which is translated as,

> And I saw a great white throne and he who is seated upon it, and the earth and the heaven fled from his presence, and a place was not found for them.

Your question concerns the antecedent of the pronoun αὐτοῖς ("for them"). Who does "them" refer to? The "teacher" you refer to wishes to believe that the singular τὸν καθήμενον ("he who is seated") suddenly becomes multi-personal and is thus the antecedent of the plural pronoun αὐτοῖς, "for them."

It seems, however, that the author is referring to the heaven and the earth which had fled from the presence of the one sitting on the throne. When they fled, there was no place found for them, since they were destroyed ([Rev. 21:1](http://www.blueletterbible.org/Bible.cfm?b=Rev&c=21&t=KJV#s=t_conc_1188001) cp. [2 Pet. 3:10-11](http://www.blueletterbible.org/Bible.cfm?b=2Pe&c=3&t=KJV#s=t_conc_1159010)).

Answer (score 3):

To add to the other fine answer, God is maintained throughout Revelation in contradistinction from the Lamb with the designation, "He who sits on the throne."

> *5:13* - "To **him who sits on the throne** and to **the Lamb** be praise and honor and glory and power, for ever and ever!"
>
> *6:16* - "Fall on us and hide us from the face of **him who sits on the throne** and from the wrath of **the Lamb**!"
>
> *7:10* - "Salvation belongs to **our God, who sits on the throne**, and to **the Lamb**."
>
> <sup>All verses from NIV, emphasis mine</sup>

In other words, the enthroned-ness is something especially peculiar to the Father in Revelation.

This is not to say that the Lamb does not share in the throne. Indeed Jesus writes to the church in Laodicea, "To the one who is victorious, I will give the right to sit with me on my throne, just as I was victorious and sat down with my Father on his throne." (3:21) Also, the first time John sees the Lamb, he says, "Then I saw a Lamb, looking as if it had been slain, standing at the center of the throne." (5:6)

But God is the one essentially named by his enthroned-ness in Revelation, so that when we come to 20:11, we already know who John is describing when he obliquely refers to "him who is seated on it" (and again in 21:5) - it is the παντοκράτωρ, the Lord God Almighty. It would therefore be unlikely for John to suddenly use the designation to refer not only to God, but also to the Lamb and the Spirit.